# Calling a Javascript function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

Well it looks like how I tried to explain before wasn't working as well. I'll just explain my full purpose, show my code and what I'm doing.
I am writing a Google Chrome extension which is mainly run with jQuery. The purpose of the extension is to provide a few css changes, script changes, and site changes to a website I am a member of. I do not have administrative access to the site so I do not have access to change the raw files and simply add an "onLoad='create_toolbar()'" attribute to the body. When the body/page/document loads, I want to run a function which is in the site's Javascript called "create_toolbar". I need to find a way to call the function of create_toolbar when the page is loaded but still run the jQuery in my extension which cleans up some bugs on the site.

Is there a way for me to call the create_toolbar function when the document is ready with jQuery? Can I append an attribute to an empty div for when onload it calls the create_toolbar function?

I've tried the following and none have worked.

```
$(document).ready(create_toolbar);
```

.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(body).attr('onLoad', 'create_toolbar()');
};
```

---

Never mind guys, I used the following code below to solve my problem:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('body').attr('onMouseOver', 'create_toolbar()');
});
```

Comment: Please show more of your code.

Comment: That will call your function when the DOM is ready. There isn't enough information in the question to really understand the issue you're having.

Comment: This should work just fine http://jsfiddle.net/KtCXM/

Comment: What is assigned to `create_toolbar` when the document ready event is raised?

Comment: BTW, jQuery is just a set of Javascript functions. Your code "in jQuery" is Javascript code. There is thus no such concept as "inside of jQuery".

Comment: To answer your question, we need to know how `create_toolbar` is defined.  Also it would be helpful to know what the error message is instead of just "none have worked"

Comment: So did you try the solutions give in the answers? None of them are in your list. The solution you came up with is... interesting.

Comment: So what if the user doesn't have the mouse pointer over the window when it loads? Your code won't fire until they move it back over the window. Also, unless you remove the attribute, the event will keep firing as the user moves the mouse pointer around the page.

Answer (score 4):

**To expand on @Gabriel's answer, in the following cases the OP's original code should work as is:**

```
function create_toolbar() {
    alert("ran it");   
};
$(document).ready(create_toolbar);
```

.

```
$(document).ready(create_toolbar);
function create_toolbar() {
    alert("ran it");   
};
```

.

```
var create_toolbar = function(){
    alert("ran it");   
};
$(document).ready(create_toolbar);
```

**In this case, the OP's code would not work, but @Gabriel's solution would:**

```
//Doesn't work
$(document).ready(create_toolbar);
var create_toolbar = function(){
    alert("ran it");   
};
```

.

```
//Works
$(document).ready(function() { create_toolbar(); });
var create_toolbar = function(){
    alert("ran it");   
};
```

The reason is that in the OP's code, `create_toolbar` needs to exist at the time the line `$(document).ready(create_toolbar);` is executed.  In @Gabriel's solution with a closure, `create_toolbar` doesn't need to exist until the document is ready.

Answer (score 3):

Closures:

```
$(document).ready(function() { create_toolbar(); });
```

Comment: Could you explain why OP's original call wouldn't work?  This looks like it should be functionally equivalent, but I'm probably missing something.

Comment: @Davy: This will help if `create_toolbar` is a local variable whose value is assigned later.

Comment: @Gabriel It still isn't working :/ I'll update my post now with my full code and my purpose of doing this.

Comment: @Gabriel I hope you didn't mind me expanding on your answer with my own.  It's too long for a comment, and I had to play around with different examples to really understand the difference.